# MIDP 2.0 push registry

Tags: java-me, push, midp-2.0

We would like to use MIDP2.0 push registry to invoke our MIDLet at regular interval to check for new messages from server. If another MIDLet is already running in the foreground will our MIDLet be able to be invoked simultaneously? Will the behavior vary from device to device (e.g. Nokia S-60, Motorola, Samsung, LG)?

Answer (score 2):

Behavior will definitely vary. Some devices can't handle multitasking (e.g. Nokia's Series 40 devices) and i highly doubt that your application will be invoked by PushRegistry while another MIDlet is running on those devices. Actually I'm not even sure that your MIDlet will be invoked (and could steal the foreground) from another running MIDlet on devices that do support multitasking (e.g. SonyEricsson). From my experience with the Java ME platform this is exactly the kind of feature that would suffer greatly from device fragmentation.