# How to do push notification in j2me?

Tags: java-me, push-notification

I want to implement push notification in j2me application.
In this the  want to keep notification when i get the certain value from the web service.

I had never done this functionality.Can anyone please help me how to get the notification message at particular time interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java ME phones don't have a regular platform for push notifications. At least not like Apple does in iOS. What exactly are you trying to do? Do you need your notifications to arrive when your app is not running? Because that's impossible in most phones supporting Java ME...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Alert For that [as shown in this Example](http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/sound-alert-example.shtml). If you need Alert after a particular time interval then you have to create `Thread`s for that which will run continuously. One thing I want to mention here is that this is possible only when your application is running.

Comment: thanks but i dont want alert in this way.I want notification like pushregistry

Comment: I think its not possible in J2ME.

Comment: But i had tried this--http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/--though this code i am getting the pushnotification message with tone whenever i switch on device

Comment: @iosdeveloper it's not reliable, [behavior will vary across devices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1625451/1429387).